# How to count special words in MS WORD using a formula?

Tags: ms-word, formula, word-field

I've a regular table added into my Word file.
Inside of this table I insert "yes" or "no", for example.
And I want to count all cells with the word "yes".

In excel it is easy to do using a formula, but I don't know how to solve this in Word

```
=COUNT(table1 E3:E40,"yes")
```

The code above does not work - it throws a syntax error. I guess it , and/or " operator.

Is it possible to do such "complex" formulas in Word?

Comment: Actually, Word *does* have a field COUNT function, but what you're describing is akin to Excel's COUNTIF function. To see how to do a wide range of calculations in Word, check out my **Microsoft Word Field Maths Tutorial**, at http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38720-microsoft-word-field-maths-tutorial.html or http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, Word does not have the same capabilities as Excel. Using field codes, a limited range of formula *calculations* is possible, but there are no *special* functions, such as  `CountA` or `CountIf`.

This would require executing a macro to test the column's cells' values and write the result. Or an Excel worksheet could be embedded in the Word document.